# Cannot Connect to Remote Registry

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, remote-desktop, windows-registry

So I'm trying to connect to another computer's registry via regedit > Connect Network Registry. The problem is that for some reason, I can connect to Computer C from Computer A, but I cannot connect to it from Computer B. Obviously, this would indicate that there is some sort of problem with Computer B.

Here is some of the trouble shooting I have done so far on Computer B:

1. Verified that the Remote Registry service is running. I also restarted it.
2. Disabled Windows Firewall.
3. Verified I could ping Computer C from Computer B.
4. Renewed Computer B's IP address.
5. Check to see if Remote Administration is allowed (shouldn't matter, Windows Firewall is off...

Also worth noting, I am unable to use psexec. My coworker apparently "cleaned out the registry", did something to .NET framework and also to .msxml. I've been looking for hours and still haven't found a fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you getting RPC unavailable?  For example, if you open up the services MMC snapin (services.msc) and connect to the remote computer, what error do you get?   Or even use just sc.exe to connect to the remote computers services.  Is https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4494.windows-server-troubleshooting-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable.aspx then relevant?

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the Windows Event Log on Computer B, especially events that mention WMI? If you run `net share` on Computer B, are the `IPC$` and `ADMIN$` shares present?

Comment: EMK:

No, I am able to use Computer B to connect to Computer C via services.msc and sc.exe. Unfortunately, I still can't connect via registry.

Twisty 17:

Not sure if I'm looking in the wrong place in Event Viewer, but I didn't really see any errors with RPC, Remote Registry, or even WMI. Of course, it's also possible that I'm looking in the wrong place... Both the IPC$ and ADMIN$ shares are present on Computer B (and Computer C).